# Square root values not being retrieved

Tags: c, pointers, square-root

I'm having a problem with getting my code to pick up the user input of the variables `number` and `result`. The correct way the code should act is: When user puts in a positive value, code should square root this value and display the new value. As of now, there are no error messages, the code runs fine, just not the way i want it to.

It does NOT pick up any value and does not square root math either, when looking at the output.

I also need to use pointers when doing this code (weird imo). Pointers are something im very new to so i expect to get quite the critique on that department.

I have tried reading several tutorials on pointers and the understanding of `sqrt` but it feels like key parts of those things still confuse me.

Code: (Consists of a function `squareRoot` that does the math and `main` that handles input/output)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> //needed for sqrt()
#define POSITIVE 1 //not used atm
#define NEGATIVE 0 //not used atm

float squareRoot(float number, float * result) {

    return * result = sqrt(number); //calculate the square root of a number

}


int main() {

    float number = 0;
    float * result = malloc(sizeof(float));

        printf("Enter a float value: ");
        scanf("%f", &number);
        squareRoot(number, result);

    if (number < 0) {
        printf("Square root of a negative value is not possible.");
    }

    if (number > 0) {
        printf("Square root if %.2f is: %.2f "), number, result;
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Any help or constructive criticism is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`result` is a pointer, you need to dereference it.

```
printf("Square root if %.2f is: %.2f ", number, *result);
```

If you didn't get a compiler warning for the type mismatch, increase your warning level.

Comment: Re "*Increase your warning level.*", For example, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with `gcc`. This will find sooo many errors.

Comment: Note also (though you've corrected it), the `)` is misplaced in the OP's code.

Comment: I assumed that was a copying error, since he said he got no error messages.

Comment: Hmm, maybe that's not actually a syntax error, it's just a statement containing the comma operator.